# Setting a collection cache key without multiple subsequent queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I've just gotten into caching for my application and a little stuck. I have a query that relies on a scope. The scope gathers the last (x) posts created on the page.

```
Rails.cache.fetch('homepage/posts') do
  posts = Post.by_latest

  render json: posts
end
```

Here's what I'm having a hard time understanding. Since I want to make sure the site displays the latest posts I don't want to manually set an expiration time or date. Instead I'd like to expire the cache when a new post is created or destroy. Here's the other dilemma. I thought of making a callback in my Post model but things get a little jumbled when I want to expire the cache of other keys but all want to accomplish the same thing.

```
def flush_cache
  Rails.cache.delete('homepage/posts')
  Rails.cache.delete('posts')
  ...
end
```

I wanted to flush the cache in more of a dynamic approach as you would with a single object...where the cache key is comprised with the `updated_at` attribute of the object and expires whenever modified. I'm finding the difficult to do with a collection though. Generating a cache key from the query would result in a query in itself, thus defeating the overall purpose of caching:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(Post.by_latest.cache_key) do
  posts = Post.by_latest

  render json: posts
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're using it in quite the correct way, Rails handles caching of collections automatically quite well.

This is the standard setup for caching a collection

```
posts = Rails.cache.fetch(Post.by_latest) do
  Post.by_latest
end

render json: posts
```